# TypeOrm creates database but unable to connect it

Tags: typescript, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to make jwt aut system, for that I decided use nestJs and sqlite.
The code generate sqlite file, but after that throw "Unable to connect to the database." I checked by sqlite terminal and realized, that tables also were not added.

here the entity

```
import {
    BeforeInsert,
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Entity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn
} from 'typeorm';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import {UserRO} from './user.dto';

@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn(`uuid`)
    id: string;
@CreateDateColumn()
created: Date;

@Column({
    type: 'text',
    unique: true
})
username: string;

@Column('text')
password: string;

@BeforeInsert()
async hashPassword() {
    this.password = await  bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
}
```

and sqlite db description from app.module

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'sqlite',
        database: 'taskDB',
        synchronize: true,
        logging: false,
        entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    }), UserModule],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
```

and this is what terminal sends

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {BeforeInsert, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from 'typeorm';
    [0]                                                                      ^
    [0]
    [0] SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    [0]     at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
    [0]     at createScript (vm.js:266:10)
    [0]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:10)
    [0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:28)
    [0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    [0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    [0]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    [0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
    [0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Comment: Okey, I just changed db to Mongo and now it working, so it isn't really relevand, but I still intresed where could be mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
```

Or this:

```
entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
```